# Asymptotic limit of trace of random matrix $(aI_m + WW^\top)^{-1}$, where $W$ has iid rows from $N(0,\Sigma)$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $m$ and $d$ be positive integers with $m,d \to \infty$ such that $m/d \to \rho \in (0,\infty)$. Let $W$ be a random $m \times d$ matrix with iid rows $w_1,\ldots,w_m \sim N(0,\Sigma)$ for a positive-definite matrix such that $\operatorname{tr} \Sigma = 1$ and $\|\Sigma\|_\text{op} = \mathcal O(1/d)$. Given $a>0$, consider the random positive-definite matrix $A := a I_m + WW^\top $.

> **Question.** What is the asymptotic limit of $(1/d)\operatorname{tr} A^{-1}$ as a function of $a$ and $\rho$, and perhaps the limiting spectral density $\mathcal D$ of the deterministic matrix $d\cdot \Sigma$ ?

Comment: The Marcenko-Pastur result provides the limit of the Stieljes transform of $WW^T$ as the solution of an equation involving integral over the limiting spectral distribution of $\Sigma$, e.g., equation (10) in https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-338j-infinite-random-matrix-theory-fall-2004/lecture-notes/handout4.pdf by taking $T_n$ there proportional to your $\Sigma$. Are you looking for a closed form solution? This might be achievable only for certain values of $a$ or certain limiting spectral distribution of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I see how to put an answer (not closed form, but implicit formula) together using MP theory.

Comment: For example, If $\Sigma=(1/d) I_d$, then it turns out that $(1/d)\mbox{trace}(A^{-1}) \to m_{MP(\rho)}(0)$, where $z \mapsto m_{MP(\rho)}(z)$ is the Stieltjes transform of the Marchenko-Pastur law with parameter $\rho$.

Comment: The fact that you wrote `\mbox{tr}` rather than `\operatorname{tr}` was conspicuous instantly when I looked at your question, before I looked at the MathJax code. Only the latter has the context-dependent spacing that makes the space to the right of $\operatorname{tr}$ bigger in $\operatorname{tr}A$ than in $\operatorname{tr}(A).$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

*incorrect answer kept for the record:*
<s>For fixed $a,\rho$ and $d\rightarrow\infty$ the matrix $A=aI+WW^{\rm T}$ self-averages to
$aI+E[WW^{\rm T}]=aI+I\operatorname{tr}\Sigma=(a+1)I,$
hence
$(1/d)\operatorname{tr}A^{-1}\rightarrow \frac{\rho}{a+1}.$</s>

Comment: Hum, yes $A$ self-averages to $aI + E[WW^\top]$, but I fail to see how this can be used to obtain information about $A^{-1}$. After all, $ E[1/x]$ has nothing to do with $1/E[x]$ in general. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: "self-averaging" of some quantity $A$ means that the statistical fluctuations around the mean $E[A]$ can be neglected, so $E[1/A]\rightarrow 1/E[A]$; in this case the fluctuations vanish as $1/d$, so $A$ becomes effectively a deterministic quantity.

Comment: Ok, I was assuming the wrong definition of "self-averaging". But still I don't know what's the correct definition thereof in the context of the above problem. By saying "$A$ self-averages around $E[A]$, do you formally mean that $A = E[A] + \Delta$, where $\|\Delta\|_{op} = o_{\mathbb P}(1)$  or something else ? If yes, what's a reference to for this claim ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the answer is not correct. Take $a=0$, $d>m+1$, and set $\Sigma=I_d/d$. Then $d*A$ is Wishart($d,I_m$) and  $E[trace[(dA)^{-1}] = m/(d-m-1)$ by the exact formula for the expectation of inverse Wishart distribution (see, e.g., the wikipedia page on inverse Wishart). The limit of the expectation is $\rho/(1-\rho)$. I don't see any reason for a discontinuity in $a$ at $a=0$.

Comment: thank you for correcting me, @jlewk --- I will keep the answer and comments for the record and cross out the text.